# iPhone4 has no picture. However, responds to touch and has sound. How can i test logic board failure?

Tags: iphone

iPhone4 has no picture/black. However, responds to touch and has sound. Just replaced the LCD screen/digitizer, and it's still black screen.

Is there anything else that I could be missing? What else can I check/test?

Comment: How do you know it's responding to touch?

Answer (score 1):

My phone was also overheating, experiencing reception problems. It looks like a bunch of dirt and grime got trapped all over the inside from the previous cracked screen.

The solution: I cleaned off all the dirt and grime off of all the parts with alcohol 70%, used rubber gloves to make sure no oil from my skin transferred to the parts, and I used a blow dryer to blow off any dust. Fixed everything. The overheating stopped and phone reception is a lot better!